# When or what makes gcc add dependencies?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, dependencies, musl

I was investigating an issue with `sudo` and at some point I've [noticed](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/f3e92c27b778f19f4269fe4cfd759e1d) that `gcc` adds `libintl` as a `sudo` dependency:

```
$ ldd src/sudo
    /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x77e7c812f000)
    libintl.so.8 => /usr/lib/libintl.so.8 (0x77e7c7d0d000)
    libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x77e7c812f000)
```

supposedly for no reason.

My guess is that if `sudo` depends on `libintl`, then one of the symbols of the latter should be in the symbol table of one of the `sudo` constituents.

`sudo` is built this way:

```
$ gcc -o sudo conversation.o error.o exec.o \
exec_pty.o get_pty.o net_ifs.o load_plugins.o \
parse_args.o sudo.o sudo_edit.o tgetpass.o \
ttysize.o utmp.o ../common/libcommon.la \
../compat/libreplace.la ...
```

and this:

```
$ { readelf -s src/conversation.o;
readelf -s src/error.o; readelf -s src/exec.o;
readelf -s src/exec_pty.o; readelf -s src/get_pty.o;
readelf -s src/net_ifs.o; readelf -s src/load_plugins.o;
readelf -s src/parse_args.o; readelf -s src/sudo.o;
readelf -s src/sudo_edit.o; readelf -s src/tgetpass.o;
readelf -s src/ttysize.o; readelf -s src/utmp.o;
readelf -s common/.libs/libcommon.a;
readelf -s compat/.libs/libreplace.a; } \
| grep -E "intl|gettext"
```

gives nothing.

What am I missing? How can I further clarify the issue? `readelf -s /usr/lib/libintl.so.8.1.4` output is in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/f3e92c27b778f19f4269fe4cfd759e1d).

**UPD**

```
$ ldd /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
        ldd (0x787ce30fe000)
```

Comment: Did you try `ldd /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1`?

Comment: maybe it needs to be tagged as `libmusl` (which doesn't provide nls/gettext api) or autoconf `configure`

Comment: @yvs2014 I can understand the `musl` tag (I've added it), but why `configure`? My guess is that `gcc` or `ld` makes a decision to add `libintl` as a dependency. Although I'm not an expert here. And by the way any suggestions how I can further clarify the issue are welcome.

Comment: `why configure`: doesn't configure script check out `nls` support api and decide which libraries to link against? like `for l in "libc" "-lintl" "-lintl -liconv"; do ... LIBS="$OLIBS $l"`

Comment: @yvs2014 `-lintl` sounds like "you can use `libintl` if it contains symbols that you need" to me. And in the [other gist](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/b9c74af59b0c8910233e882d8798c26a) depending on whether I actually make use of `_()` `libintl` appears or not in the deps. I believe although `configure` checks if libs are present and provides env vars, what actually adds dependencies is `gcc` or `ld`. And they does it not because they were passed `-litnl`, but because the executable needs some symbol. I.e. from my experiments if it's passed `-lintl`, `libintl` is not necessarily in the deps.

Comment: >if it's passed -lintl, libintl is not necessarily in the deps< it's easy to test out with `echo 'int main() {}' | cc -o a -lintl -xc - && ldd a`

Comment: if you don't need nls support (which presented by libintl on a target os and detectable by configure script), it's disableable by `configure --disable-nls` as it reads from its help

Comment: @yvs2014 As you know, I already tested it out, but I've just tested it out [your way](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/f5c682d0037e4cba0bbe0892fa585ebd). And of course you can disable things with `./configure` (although [not in this case](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/c60b8b1f1890dd4a60d35d1b412a4883)), but that's beside the point. I'm not trying to make it not add `libintl` as a dependency. I'm trying to understand why `gcc` adds a dependency where it supposedly shouldn't.

Comment: "already tested it out, but I've just tested it ..." likely on different os versions with distinct cc/linkers. Have you tried that one-liner on os (alpine:3.4) from the original question?

Comment: @yvs2014 Indeed, on 3.5 and with `96b7c1f0f` by default `sudo` doesn't depend on `libintl`, but if I wrap something in `_()` it starts to. That's what I meant by the first test. On 3.4 it always depends on `libintl` although the latter doesn't seem to be used. That's what's the mystery to me. And indeed with [your test](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/1b4c19891be50b2b8801689de1487009) on 3.4 the result depends on `libintl`. Does that mean that with the 3.4's `gcc` it adds everything passed via `-l` as dependencies, on >= 3.5 only those libs that are really needed?

Comment: Yes, I think it's correct that every lib mentioned on the command line is added on alpine3.4. And it looks like with alpine:3.5 there was a big DSO-linking change in `ld` (from `--no-as-needed` default to `--as-needed`). So that to get the same behaviour with different `ld` defaults it needs to be specified by your own. Like `echo 'int main() {}' | cc -o a -Wl,--as-needed -lintl -Wl,--no-as-needed -xc - && ldd a` versus `echo 'int main() {}' | cc -o a -Wl,--no-as-needed -lintl -Wl,--as-needed -xc - && ldd a`

Comment: Not sure, supposedly it helps on alpine:3.4 `LDFLAGS=-Wl,--as-needed ./configure && make` , but `-Wl,--as-needed -lintl -Wl,--no-as-needed` is more accurate with no impact on other libs there

Comment: @yvs2014 Thanks for your replies. Can you possibly give a link to the commit, or a changelog entry?

Comment: sorry, nope, I'm not too into systems with musl, there was just a cursory glance from common point of view

Answer (score 1):

[By default](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=ld/ld.texi;h=ca9574dfc71bf46f3ace541fb544cdcbb061c497;hb=ec6f962151998434f9cc743386f2a49a1ce1a0f6#l1697) the linker adds every library passed via `-l` as a dependency:

> Normally the linker will add a DT_NEEDED tag for each dynamic library mentioned on the command line, regardless of whether the library is actually needed or not.

The `--as-needed` switch was supposedly [added](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commitdiff;h=4a43e768f18f325a0e52de37fe69d4a6a764d668) in [2.15.90](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=bfd/configure.in;h=e08a663dcdb2a4b265018a5ce8288aeb8db9232b;hb=4a43e768f18f325a0e52de37fe69d4a6a764d668#l10). With it a library is added only if it contains symbols needed by the code.

So in Alpine Linux 3.4 (`gcc-5.3.0`) it [behaves normally](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/4434e03e59d0ed8a730410e9ebc4d05c): it gets `-lintl`, and adds `libintl` as a dependency.

In Alpine Linux >= 3.5 (`gcc-6.2.1`) it behaves as if `--as-needed` was passed: it gets `-lintl`, but it doesn't add the library as a dependency, because it was not used (referenced).

And the last piece of the puzzle is the [Alpine Linux commit](https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/commit/?id=5b7befa1b989315a57f4fb49b8381ce06ded96c9) (`5.3.0 -> 6.1.0`) that makes `gcc` pass `--as-needed` to the linker.

Actually it can be reproduced [more easily](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/1b4c19891be50b2b8801689de1487009) (thanks yvs2014).